# simply replacing float with double didn't worked for me

Tags: c

using double gives unusual value. i didn't get expexted output.
***I'm new in C.***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double test;

    scanf("%f", &test);
    printf("the input is %f", test);


    return 0;
}
```

no matter what i enter the output is still same.
for example i entered 45

```
45
the input is 0.000000
```

Comment: `%f` is for reading `float`. Use `%lf` to read `double`.

Comment: user13546893, Enable all compiler warnings to save time.

Comment: @MikeCAT Dear, then also i got output of same precision level of float.

Comment: You can try printing with `printf("the input is %.15f", test)`

Comment: `scanf` is not `printf` but there are some similarities. In `printf` a `float` *value* is promoted to `double` but not in `scanf`, where the *pointer* must be of the right type.

Comment: @user13546893 Yes, this is one point where C is a bit confusing. For reading a `double` you need `%lf` but for printing you can just do `%f`.

Comment: Debug tip: Change printing `"%f"` to `"%e"`, `"%g"`, or `"%a"`.  They are more informative with small values and not so verbose with large ones.